# Plot multi categorical data in Python

Tags: python, visualization, dashboard, analysis

```
Month,Cluster,Count
7,Linux,42
7,Linux,56
7,Pct,6
7,Pct(C),11
7,Memory,28
10,Latency,73

10,Linux,47
10,Pct,21
10,Pct(C),18
10,Swap,41
10,Protection ,509
```

I need to compare Month here 7,10 and plot cluster for each month. How to visualize this data in python. I need to differentiate cluster count for both months

Comment: what have you tried? what libraries are you using or willing to use? what's the background? and for last what's the type of visualization you are aimming to?

Answer (score 1):

You only have one observation for Latency, Memory and swap
So you cant plot a line for the change in these, but you could combine a scatter plot with a lineplot like so

```
import pandas as pd
import io

strdata = '''
Month,Cluster,Count
7,Linux,42
7,Linux,56
7,Pct,6
7,Pct(C),11
7,Memory,28
10,Latency,73
10,Linux,47
10,Pct,21
10,Pct(C),18
10,Swap,41
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(strdata),sep=",")

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Month','Cluster']).set_index("Month").groupby("Cluster")["Count"].plot(legend=True, marker=".")
df.set_index("Month").groupby("Cluster")["Count"].plot(legend=True, style=".")
```